# How to remove the directory which shows "resource busy"?

Tags: directory, nfs

I used the following command `rm -rf inttergat` to remove the directory. But I get stuck with following errors:

```
rpa-vd1-296: rm -rf inttegrat/
rm: cannot remove ‘inttegrat/.nfs0000000005d154320000000b’: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your files are on an NFS mount (a "network share" if you prefer). Something is using one of the files inside the `inttegrat` directory and NFS is keeping it safe until they have finished with it.

An alternative option is to rename the directory out of the way, and then try deleting it later.

```
mv inttegrat inttegrat.DELETE_ME_LATER
...
rm -rf inttegrat.DELETE_ME_LATER
```